# in java variable length argument concept . but i am getting the wrong answer again

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(int ...i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

class Demo1 {
    public static void main(String ...s) {
        Demo.main(1);
    }    
}
```

answer is [I@659e0bfd

Comment: What is the 'right' answer?

Comment: it should be  1 after run Demo1.class . it is passing the hash code rather than 1 from the main method

Comment: sorry i didnt get u ?

Comment: No, `Demo1#main` is passing 1 to `Demo#main`

Comment: @Abhi: No, it's not passing the hash code, it's passing `1`. (For that matter, `[I@659e0bfd` isn't a hashcode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i
```

is an integer array. By printing `i` you are printing the reference variable
not the element of the array.

As everything is represented via objects in java except primitive datatypes
printing `i` gives `proxyclassname@hexadecimalcode` of class calculated by the JVM.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of varargs which denotes a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function):

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments.

As understood, `i` is an array of integers in `Demo`.
What you probably want is:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(int ...i) {
        System.out.println(i[0]);
    }
}
```

Make sure to test the array's length.

Currently you're printing the class: `[I@659e0bfd` This denotes an array of integers (notice the bracket `[` which means array and `I` which means integer).

Comment: thanks bro but if changes int to string .. it is not going to work .. public try class Demo {
public static void main(String ...i){
 System.out.println(i);
}
}

 class Demo1{
 public static void main(String ...s){
  Demo.main("a");
 } 
 
}

Answer (score 2):

`i` is an array, that's what the `...i` notation means: "All the arguments from this point onward, as an array." That's why when you output it, you get that default string from the array's `toString` method.

To output the contents of the array, either loop through it or index into it:

```
for (int n : i) {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

If you put that in `Demo.main`, you'd see it output `1` (since that's the only entry in the array).

Here's another example of `...` notation, which hopefully makes it a bit clearer:

```
static void foo(String first, String second, String ...more) {
    System.out.println("first: " + first);
    System.out.println("second: " + second);
    for (String s : more) {
        System.out.println("and: " + s);
    }
}
```

If you call that:

```
foo("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
```

Note how I'm calling it with five arguments, but only three are declared. The third one, `more`, with the `...`, gets all of the arguments from that point onward. So the call above gives us

```
first: one
second: two
and: three
and: four
and: five
```

Comment: thk .. what if changes int to String .. eg                                                                                                      public class Demo {
public static void main(String ...i){
 System.out.println(i);
}
}

 class Demo1{
 public static void main(String ...s){
  Demo.main("a");
 } 
 
}

Comment: @Abhi: Then it will be a `String` array instead of an `int` array.

Comment: yes  String array will be there . so now what to do ?

Comment: @Abhi: "What to do" **what**? What's the goal?

Comment: thk for responding sir . i just got the answer .. i forget to convert it into string using the for loop .

Answer (score 1):

`int ...i` means `varargs`. So though you pass 1 as a int (not as an array) you have to access the varargs similar to array
e.g. `i[0] -> 1`
Since you are printing just the varargs it will print the hashcode of the object

Answer (score 0):

The `toString` Method on array objects is not implemented in a way you expect it. You have to use [`Arrays.toString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array) to print the array content.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.tostring(t));
```

The reason you get an array is becaus of the ellipses. These are var args in java. That means, all the arguments for this parameter get wrapped in a array. Something like this:

```
 Demo.main(new int[] {1});//compiler generated code
```